# How to handle JSON Parse Error in Spring Rest Web Service

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a rest web service developed with Spring Boot.I am able to handle all the exceptions that occur due to my code, but suppose the json object that the client posts is not compatible with the object that i want to desrialize it with, I get

```
"timestamp": 1498834369591,
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message": "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize value
```

I wanted to know is there a way that for this exception, I can provide the client a custom exception message. I am not sure how to handle this error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To customize this message per Controller, use a combination of `@ExceptionHandler` and `@ResponseStatus` within your Controllers:

```
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "CUSTOM MESSAGE HERE")
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    public void handleException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex) {
        //Handle Exception Here...
    }
```

If you'd rather define this once and handle these Exceptions globally, then use a `@ControllerAdvice` class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomControllerAdvice {
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "CUSTOM MESSAGE HERE")
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    public void handleException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex) {
        //Handle Exception Here...
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you handle the exception if you don't know what caused it? The `handleException` method doesn't receive the Exception or any other parameter. -- *Edit*: ok, that was a dumb question... you can add parameters to it, such as the Exception itself, and Spring will do his usual magic.

Comment: The answer would be better with an example argument `  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "CUSTOM MESSAGE HERE")
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    public void handleException(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`

Comment: I edited the answer to include the exception in the hand method signature.

Answer (score 3):

You also can extend **ResponseEntityExceptionHandler** and override the method **handleHttpMessageNotReadable** (example in Kotlin, but very similar in Java):

```
override fun handleHttpMessageNotReadable(ex: HttpMessageNotReadableException, headers: HttpHeaders, status: HttpStatus, request: WebRequest): ResponseEntity<Any> {
    val entity = ErrorResponse(status, ex.message ?: ex.localizedMessage, request)
    return this.handleExceptionInternal(ex, entity as Any?, headers, status, request)
}
```